# How to get started with Java modules?

Tags: java, module, jvm, osgi, jboss-modules

I'm reading about OSGi and JBoss modules. I understand the purpose of modules -- to avoid Jar hell and conflicting classes -- but I don't know where to start if I want to write a new application that uses them. Is there a kernel somewhere that I can start with, that then loads the other modules?  I don't want to run Eclipse or Wildfly; I want to start fresh with my own app. Hello world for modules.

Edit: I'm using IntelliJ, and for several reasons I really don't want to switch to Eclipse. So I can't do much with answers that require I install Eclipse plugins.

Comment: What sort of application are you trying to write?

Comment: There are a few, but mainly web applications. I could use Wildfly, but I'd like to try something smaller, like Undertow + modules. Maybe that's all Wildfly is, but it looks much bigger.

Comment: I haven't used undertow or wildfly, but you may be able to embed something like [apache felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html) into your undertow application. Have you had a look at the apache karaf osgi container?

Comment: If you really want IntelliJ support for modular Java development then I recommend telling JetBrains that you would pay them for it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100812. In the meantime, your unwillingness to experiment with alternative tools may hold you back from learning something. I find this attitude puzzling. I'm an Eclipse user but would happily experiment with IntelliJ or even NetBeans if they offered support for something I wanted to learn. It doesn't mean I would have to switch IDEs for all my other work.

Comment: In my case I've experimented a lot, with too many things, Eclipse and NetBeans among them. If I can't write a "hello world" in OSGi without downloading an Eclipse plugin, then OSGi is not the technology I'm looking for.  JBoss modules seem to do exactly what I'm looking for, but apparently some disagree with this. I'm going to use them for now.

Answer (score 3):

OSGi would be the first choice. JBoss Modules is still much more an internal JBoss thing than a general purpose modularity solution.

To start with an OSGi application, take a look at [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org). This is an Eclipse plugin to make OSGi development easy. From there you can create a "run configuration" which is the definition of your application. From there you can also export the application to a single executable JAR to distribute your app.

This is a nice [video](https://vimeo.com/user17212182/review/111403834/816e80e4d0) to get you started. 
Also, for more high level components (REST, databases, scheduling etc.) take a look at [Amdatu](http://amdatu.org).

Comment: Thanks, but I should have mentioned I'm not using Eclipse. I'm curious if the following link changes your view of JBoss modules? Before you guys answered my research was taking me in that direction.  http://planet.jboss.org/post/modularized_java_with_jboss_modules

Comment: I know this post, but it doesn't change my view. Note that I actually did some work with Jboss modules in the past. A big issues is that lack of a services layer, because that's a requirement to actually create modular applications. Modularity is more than just class loading...

Comment: Currently Bndtools only works with Eclipse unfortunately. There is work being done to port this to Intellij however (by Intellij): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100812

Answer (score 1):

Try starting with OSGi enRoute: http://enroute.osgi.org/. This is a project, still in development, to demonstrate using OSGi.

Comment: Thanks, but their tutorial requires Eclipse. I forgot to add to my question that I'm using IntelliJ, and I'm too invested there to switch IDEs for this.